# Passing current user for Windows Auth on an Intranet web service

Tags: vb.net, tomcat, windows-authentication

I have a Visual Basic application that obtains XML from an Intranet web service, this works just fine. However there is one page that requires Windows Authentication (due to security). The web service is running on Apache Tomcat 7 - using WAFFLE to use Windows auth. This works just fine in a web browser, Internet Explorer silently logs in the user.
([This is the method used](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatSingleSignOnValve.md))

Here is the code I'm using to obtain the XML from a provided string URL.

```
 Dim xmlResolver As XmlUrlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver()
 WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Impersonate()
 xmlResolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
 Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
 settings.IgnoreComments = True
 settings.XmlResolver = xmlResolver
 Dim xmlReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sURL, settings)

 Do While (xmlReader.Read())
 //Parsing Code
 Loop
 xmlReader.Close()
```

This works fine getting the XML for the unprotected pages, however I get the following exception when attempting to retrieve the XML from the secured page:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings)
   at PublicWebServiceTester.frmAlarms.raiseAlarm() in ..\frmAlarms.vb:line 44
```

It seems to me that the user isn't get passed through correctly.

Comment: I'd change the tag to VB.NET as this is a VBA section and may take longer to get answered.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks, that was by mistake